# Adding "Cortana Suggestions" to Web Page

Tags: microsoft-edge

Does anyone know how to add metadata for "Cortana Suggestions" to a web page? For example, if (in Edge) you go to: http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/home you will see a Cortana message "Can I interest you in a coupon" in the address bar.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read here : https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2015/09/16/get-quick-results-with-microsoft-edge-and-cortana/

it is a feature that is driven by the Cortana team:

> We will be increasing availability and the number of retailers we support in the months ahead through our partnership with Shopular, a leading coupon provider.

You could create a Hosted web app from your web site as explained here : https://microsoftedge.github.io/WebAppsDocs/en-US/win10/CreateHWA.htm 
Then you could be able to offer cortana support from windows 10 for the users that install your app.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like this is out of a developers control for the time being. Thanks again!